# Asus Rog Strix Z370 EGAMING Wireless card not working

Tags: networking, drivers, realtek-wireless

I have Asus ROG STRIX Z370-E GAMING motherboard with wireless card built in (**Realtek RTL8822BE**). I'm running Mint 18.3 x64 and the system doesn't seem to "see" the device. There are no linux drivers on producer's website, I've tried installing them via **ndiswrapper**. Apparently the driver is installed correctly and device is recognized, but I still don't see the option to connect to wireless network anywhere.

```
$ndsiwrapper -l
netrtwlane : driver installed
device (10EC:B822) present
```

System details shows the following in the network section:

```
Network:   Card-1: Intel Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
           driver: e1000e v: 3.2.6-k bus-ID: 00:1f.6 chip-ID: 8086:15b8
           IF: enp0s31f6 state: down mac: <filter>
           Card-2: Realtek Device b822 port: d000 bus-ID: 04:00.0 chip-ID: 10ec:b822
       IF: N/A state: N/A speed: N/A duplex: N/A mac: N/A
```

Any ideas who should I proceed to get the wireless module to work?

Comment: Mint is off-topic here, but I posted an answer rather than voting to close, because the solution is the same for Ubuntu. I hope our Ubuntu friends will search for and find this answer.

Comment: I'm aware that this is Ubuntu forum, but since Mint is based on Ubuntu I thought I'll get the highest chances for an answer here :).

Comment: @rufus1530 - it's been brought to my attention that the pesky **rtl8822be** should work out of the box in 18.04. It's very possible that it does. It'd be great if it does, in fact. If you get the chance to test an Ubuntu 18.04 Live USB on your machine then it'd be good to know if it's still being problematic. I can then stop my crusade about the **rtl8822be** and focus on the **rtl8821ce** ;)

Comment: @pHeLiOn - you're correct, the rtl8822be works out of the box in 18.04. 'How' it works is a topic for different thread through :). But yeah, you can consider this problem solved, thanks!

Comment: @rufus1530 - that's great news! Really appreciate you testing that & that'll help troubleshooting any further **rtl8822be** issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I'd remove ndiswrapper:

```
sudo apt-get purge ndiswrapper*
```

Next, with a temporary working internet connection, do:

```
wget https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/archive/extended.zip
unzip extended.zip
cd rtlwifi_new-extended
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtl8822be
```

If, after the 'make' step, you have errors, please post them here. Warnings are probably alright.

**EDIT**: You have compiled the driver for your current running kernel only. When Update Manager installs a later one, also known as linux-image, after the requested reboot, re-compile:

```
cd ~/rtlwifi_new-extended
make clean
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtl8822be
```

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few moments. Glad it's working.

Comment: @chili555 The return I get from ‘make’ is `make -C /lib/modules/4.13.0-37-generic/build M=/home/rowand/rtlwifi_new-extended modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-37-generic'
arch/x86/Makefile:153: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
./scripts/gcc-version.sh: line 25: gcc: command not found
./scripts/gcc-version.sh: line 26: gcc: command not found
make[1]: gcc: Command not found
make[1]: gcc: Command not found
make[1]: gcc: Command not found
make[1]: gcc: Command not found`

Comment: `make[1]: gcc: Command not found
  CC [M]  /home/rowand/rtlwifi_new-extended/base.o
/bin/sh: 1: gcc: not found
scripts/Makefile.build:308: recipe for target '/home/rowand/rtlwifi_new-extended/base.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/rowand/rtlwifi_new-extended/base.o] Error 127
Makefile:1550: recipe for target '_module_/home/rowand/rtlwifi_new-extended' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/rowand/rtlwifi_new-extended] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-37-generic'
Makefile:87: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2`

Comment: @AndrewConley Please install the package *build-essential* and try again. If that doesn't fix it, start your own new question and we'll help you.

Comment: @chili555 That worked. Many thanks! I am using a Thinkpad E580 in case that helps anyone find the answer they need. Also, is it worth editing the title of the question or mentioning in the answer that this relates to the Realtek rtl8822be?

Comment: In the answer, it says, `sudo modprobe rtl8822be` so I'd guess it's clear enough. Glad it's working.

Comment: I don't know, but I doubt that the question will be deleted. It is curious, however, that an answer that was accepted and upvoted numerous times, is closed. AU giveth and AU taketh away. Of course, you could ask the question yourself @pHeLiOn and specifically refer to Ubuntu. I will answer with a few refinements.

Comment: @chili555 - rufus very kindly tested his wifi with a live USB of 18.04 and it does indeed appear to work out of the box. This is indeed good news & should help troubleshooting 18.04 issues with the **rtl8822be**. (i.e the driver *should* be there so, if not, there's some problem with it being detected)