# No WIFI on Lenovo ThinkPad E580 when installing Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, wireless, thinkpad, realtek-wireless

I bought the [Lenovo ThinkPad E580](https://www3.lenovo.com/de/de/laptops/thinkpad/edge-series/ThinkPad-E580/p/20KSCTO1WWDEDE2/customize?) without operating system and I am trying to install Ubuntu 16.04. Everything is working so far, except the WIFI is not. The strange thing is, that the internet is working when I plug in a LAN cable.

I think a wireless driver must be missing, but I can't figure out, which one I have to install. At the website of Lenovo it says that the Laptop should have the wireless adapter "Intel Dual Band Wireless 3165 AC". But I cant find that one.

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -i net -A2
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:5068]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r816

$ sudo lshw -class network
  *-network
      description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 10
       serial: 8c:16:45:00:99:5e
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:128 ioport:c000(size=256) memory:f2304000-f2304fff memory:f2300000-f2303fff

$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 06cb:00a2 Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 5986:2113 Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:b023 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0e8f:00a7 GreenAsia Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

$ rfkill list all
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

$ dmesg | grep -i firmware
[    0.169227] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    1.612093] i915 0000:00:02.0: Direct firmware load for i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_01.bin failed with error -2
[    1.612095] i915 0000:00:02.0: Failed to load DMC firmware [https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/firmware], disabling runtime power management.
[    1.957908] [drm] Found UVD firmware Version: 1.79 Family ID: 16
[    1.958925] [drm] Found VCE firmware Version: 52.4 Binary ID: 3
[    3.777769] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8822b_config.bin failed with error -2
[    3.777777] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8822b_fw.bin failed with error -2
[    3.778662] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8822b_config.bin failed with error -2
[    3.778668] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8822b_fw.bin failed with error -2
[    7.428180] psmouse serio2: trackpoint: IBM TrackPoint firmware: 0x10, buttons: 3/3
```

Comment: I believe this is your device: `Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device b822` Please run: `lspci -nnk | grep Realtek` Is the pci.id 10ec:b822? If so, except for the ndiswrapper part, your answer is this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1004014/asus-rog-strix-z370-egaming-wireless-card-not-working

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Did you already tried this [Step-By-Step guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting.html)?

Comment: When I run `lspci -nnk | grep Realtek` i get  `03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
05:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b822]`

Comment: I followed the instructions in your link and now it is working!! Thank you so much!!!