# New install - no network devices available - Realtek Device b822

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless, lenovo, realtek-wireless

I just purchased a Lenovo Yoga 730 15" laptop, and installed Ubuntu 16.04 in place of Windows 10. Install seemingly worked fine, but now I have no wifi device available.  Tried a reinstall just to be sure, and the same issue is happening. I don't believe it to be a hardware issue, as wifi was working without issue on Windows before I wiped it out.

When I run `rfkill list` I see:

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

But when I run `lspci` I only see one item in the list claiming to be a network device:

```
3a:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device b822 (rev ff)
```

I have a USB wifi adapter and that gets me connected without issue, but obviously that is not the desired solution.  Does anyone have any insight on what might be causing the issue?

Output from `modinfo -p rtl8822be`:

```
fix_rate: (int)
debug_level: (int)
swenc:Set to 1 for software crypto (default 0)
(bool)
ips:Set to 0 to not use link power save (default 1)
(bool)
swlps:Set to 1 to use SW control power save (default 0)
(bool)
fwlps:Set to 1 to use FW control power save (default 1)
(bool)
msi:Set to 1 to use MSI interrupts mode (default 1)
(bool)
dma64:Set to 1 to use DMA 64 (default 0)
(bool)
aspm:Set to 1 to enable ASPM (default 1)
(int)
debug:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0)
debug_mask:Set debug mask (default 0) (ullong)
disable_watchdog:Set to 1 to disable the watchdog (default 0)
(bool)
```

Comment: What is the kernel version `uname -a`?

Comment: 4.13.0-45-generic #50~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 30 11:18:27 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux @Pilot6

Comment: Please edit to include results from terminal for `modinfo -p rtl8822be`

Comment: @Jeremy31 - Added output

Answer (score 4):

The current Ubuntu kernel doesn't support this new adapter. You need to install a driver. Connect to the Internet and run in a terminal:

```
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88.git
sudo dkms add ./rtw88
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
```

Now reboot and disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

If there are any errors, please tell us in comments.

Comment: When running `sudo dkms add ./rtlwifi-new` I get:

     Directory: /usr/src/.-rtlwifi-new does not exist.

The rtlwifi directory does exist in /home

Comment: I changed the 3rd command. It is `_` instead of `-`. Run it now.

Comment: It ran successfully, but still not working after reboot.  Now without my USB adapter plugged in it says "Wi-FI network (Realtek) device not ready"

`rfkill list` gives me one new output:

    1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

Comment: Did you disable Secure Boot in BIOS?

Comment: Somehow Secure Boot was turned back on.  I turned it off again, now it says disconnected instead of device not ready, and gives no option to select an available network.

Comment: Well, I have no other info. This driver should work.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Am I correct in thinking that a future kernel would better support this hardware?

Comment: Yes, it should be added to the mainline kernel sometime. You can ask Larry Finger, who is packaging these drivers for linux for some help.

Comment: Hi @Pilot6 - I've seen quite a few 'Wifi doesn't work' questions from new users recently and have been pointing the **rtl8822be** issues towards chili555's answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1004014/asus-rog-strix-z370-egaming-wireless-card-not-working/1004019#comment1758800_1004019. This answer is for 16.04 but was wondering if it would work for 18.04 (perhaps the `rtlwifi-new/0.6` is specific to 16.04?). The use of **dkms** is preferable as it doesn't require recompiling the module when the kernel's updated - possibly collaborate with chili555 or post dkms solution as alternative?

Comment: @pHeLiOn This chip is supported out of the box in 18.04.

Comment: Yup. So I might have been combining the RTL8821CE problems along with the RTL8822BE together to make it seem more like a wireless failure epidemic in my head :) I've noticed them both cropping up recently and I think there's still a few cases of the rtl8822be needing attention and not working 'out of the box' but it might not be the 'Linux disaster' that I thought it was! Thankfully :) Will delete hysterical post above.

Comment: @Pilot6 - two recent rtl8822be questions for 18.04: An HP 'All-in-one' - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1067286/still-no-wifi-adapter-for-realtek-rtl8822be-found-in-18-04#comment1759649_1067286 & Asus Wireless motherboard - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068797/asus-rog-strix-z370-e-wireless-not-working-continued. I believe in both cases it didn't work out of the box but then they followed the older fixes to install the driver so there may be further complications. If you get the chance, any advice for them would be much appreciated.