# ASUS ROG STRIX Z370-E Wireless not working (continued)

Tags: wireless, 18.04, asus

I also have Asus ROG STRIX Z370-E GAMING motherboard with wireless card built in but running Ubuntu 18.04. I tried chili555 answer in post:

[Asus Rog Strix Z370 EGAMING Wireless card not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1004014/asus-rog-strix-z370-egaming-wireless-card-not-working?newreg=3311494c99da4c16b06085d5a84c21b2)

I do not have enough reputation to comment their, also my post is a bit long. When I ran `make` I was warned that

```
Makefile:976: "Cannot use CONFIG_STACK_VALIDATION=y, please install libelf-dev, libelf-devel or elfutils-libelf-devel"
```

So I tried this

```
sudo apt install libelf-dev
make clean
make
```

which seemed to work

```
..
..
Install rtlwifi SUCCESS
```

however the last line gave an error:

```
sudo modprobe rtl8822be
# modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtl8822be': Exec format error
```

**[edit]**

@Jeremy31

```
$ modinfo rtl8823be | egrep -i 'file|vermagic'
modinfo: ERROR: Module rtl8823be not found.

$ modinfo 8823be | egrep -i 'file|vermagic'
modinfo: ERROR: Module 8823be not found.

$ modinfo rtl8822be | egrep -i 'file|vermagic'
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-33-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8822be/rtl8822be.ko
vermagic:       4.15.0-33-generic SMP mod_unload 

$ modinfo 8822be | egrep -i 'file|vermagic'
modinfo: ERROR: Module 8822be not found.
```

@chili555

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b822]
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:8746]
    Kernel driver in use: r8822be
    Kernel modules: r8822be, rtl8822be

$ lsmod | grep 882
r8822be               851968  0
mac80211              778240  3 rtl_pci,r8822be,rtlwifi
cfg80211              622592  3 mac80211,r8822be,rtlwifi
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include results for `modinfo rtl8823be | egrep -i 'file|vermagic'`

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: It looks like one command doesn't find rtl8823be and the other command does, seems kinda odd.

Comment: What about `modinfo 8823be | egrep -i 'file|vermagic'`

Comment: Please show us: `lsmod | grep 882`

Comment: Try with 8822be and rtl8822be for modinfo command with grep

Comment: @Jeremy31 modinfo rtl8822be returned a filename and vermagic. All this is way beyond me, I am not sure how to interpret these results, please help.

Comment: That looks good, what is result for `mokutil --sb-state`  Normally the exec format error is the result of the kernel version in the file name not matching the vermagic.  It might help if you looked at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) and provided results for the wireless script

Answer (score 0):

Open `Software & Updates` from the start menu. Go to the `Additional Drivers` tab. There you will find the options to select your Wi-Fi and Graphics drivers. It will look like the image in the following link: https://ibb.co/gWd3yU

You may select the options I've selected. Then press `Apply Changes`. And hopefully, you are done.

Comment: "Additional Drivers" only installs driver for Broadcom devices. He has none.