# rtl8822be on 18.04.1 (New Install on Lenovo Legion y530)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 18.04, realtek-wireless

Same problem with Realtek Device b822 as discussed in [rtl8723ae unstable on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/629679/908095) and [New install - no network devices available - Realtek Device b822](https://askubuntu.com/q/1057900/908095). Tried installing rtl8822be with and without dkms. None of them works. Here are the details: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/XkJjD6YmHZ/.

Sometimes, it says "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found". Sometimes, it is  "No visible networks".

**Updates**

I did this:

```
wget https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/archive/extended.zip
unzip extended.zip
cd rtlwifi_new-extended
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtl8822be
```

Got stuck in `sudo modprobe rtl8822be`. It gives me `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtl8822be': Exec format error`. Also, this my `dmesg | grep rtl8822be` output:

```
[   20.265500] r8822be: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8822befw.bin
[   39.784639] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 1076 at /build/linux-vxxS7y/linux-4.15.0/drivers/staging/rtlwifi/rtl8822be/fw.c:239 rtl8822be_fill_h2c_cmd+0x1ac/0x660 [r8822be]
[   39.784685] RIP: 0010:rtl8822be_fill_h2c_cmd+0x1ac/0x660 [r8822be]
```

And, this is my `dmesg | grep r8822be` output (redoing the whole thing after disconnecting from the internet):

```
[ 9334.006706] r8822be: halmac_init_hal failed
[ 9334.006865] r8822be: halmac_init_hal failed
[ 9334.007017] r8822be: halmac_init_hal failed
[ 9334.007168] r8822be: halmac_init_hal failed
[ 9334.007319] r8822be: halmac_init_hal failed
[ 9334.007470] r8822be: halmac_init_hal failed
[ 9334.007620] r8822be: halmac_init_hal failed
[ 9334.007771] r8822be: halmac_init_hal failed
[ 9334.007922] r8822be: halmac_init_hal failed
[ 9334.008073] r8822be: halmac_init_hal failed
[ 9340.045331] r8822be: [ERR]Pwr cmd polling timeout!!
[ 9340.045337] r8822be: [ERR]Pwr cmd offset : 5!!
[ 9340.045340] r8822be: [ERR]Pwr cmd value : 0!!
[ 9340.045343] r8822be: [ERR]Pwr cmd msk : 2!!
[ 9340.045346] r8822be: [ERR]Read offset = 5 value = 2!!
[ 9340.045349] r8822be: [Err]pwr sub seq parser fail, status = 0x28!
[ 9340.045352] r8822be: Handle power off cmd error
```

Any help will be appreciated greatly!

PS: I was using my phone (creating a personal hotspot) to access the internet via bluetooth.

Comment: Please run: `cd rtlwifi_new-extended` and next: `make clean` and next: `git pull` and finally: `make` and show us the last 5-8 lines at the end of 'make'. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply. I greatly appreciate it. After doing `git pull` , I get this error  `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

Comment: @chili555 I reinstalled my Ubuntu 18.04. Also, used a new live USB (the one used previously had 1 problem) to install it. Then, I tried your instructions given in [Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2364383&page=4). For now, my Wi-Fi is working. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf I added the line:
`blacklist ideapad_laptop`

and in the bios, I disabled secureboot in accordance with other similar posts I found online.

if you just want to test this as a solution, do:`sudo rmmod ideapad_laptop`

I think you will find networks are available immediately. This worked on Ubuntu 18.10