# Legion Y530-15ICH doesn't detect wireless adapter

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

The spec says it should have:

> WiFi 802.11ac 2X2

Doesn't say what card

but `ip link list`, `rfkill list`, `lspci` -- none of them find anything related to Wi-Fi. `dmesg` log also has no mention of anything related to Wi-Fi.  It's like it's not there at all...

(Note, this laptop has very serious issues with ACPI, `dmesg` log is full of errors related to it.  It also cannot detect an HDD that the spec says it should have.  BIOS cannot detect this HDD either.)

I've tried blacklisting `ideapad_laptop` module and loading `r8822eb` module -- neither made any difference (and I doubt they will, since, well, nobody apparently, can see this device).

Any clues as to what could be done? I've already wasted two days trying to install any Linux on this laptop, and it would be a total waste if I have to return it...

I've seen this, but it doesn't sound promising... [rtl8822be on 18.04.1 (New Install on Lenovo Legion y530)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1105025/rtl8822be-on-18-04-1-new-install-on-lenovo-legion-y530)

---

```
$ lspci -nnk
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [8086:3ec4] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3802]
    Kernel driver in use: skl_uncore
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) [8086:1901] (rev 07)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3e9b]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:39fe]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem [8086:1903] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem [17aa:381f]
    Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device
00:08.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model [8086:1911]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model [17aa:384e]
00:12.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller [8086:a379] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3807]
    Kernel driver in use: intel_pch_thermal
    Kernel modules: intel_pch_thermal
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller [8086:a36d] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3803]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:14.2 RAM memory [0500]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM [8086:a36f] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3801]
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a368] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3806]
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a369] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3809]
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller [8086:a360] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:380e]
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
00:17.0 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a353] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:380a]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:1d.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port 9 [8086:a330] (rev f0)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1d.5 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a335] (rev f0)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1e.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a328] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:380f]
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a30d] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3810]
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS [8086:a348] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3812]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller [8086:a323] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3813]
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller [8086:a324] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3801]
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] [10de:1c8d] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Lenovo GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] [17aa:39fe]
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
06:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981 [144d:a808]
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:a801]
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
    Kernel modules: nvme
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:38b4]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

---

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 13d3:56a6 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:b023 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please run the terminal commands: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and: `lsusb` Next, edit your question to add the result.

Comment: @chili555 Like I said, `lspci` doesn't see this device, so, grepping for 0280 gives no output. I posted all of it instead. I also added the `lsusb` output.

Comment: Is there any option in the BIOS/EFI to enable/disable wireless?

Comment: @chili555 Not that I've noticed, but I'll look at it again once I'm home. To be honest, I don't remember any settings related to networking or PCI devices. I could get into EFI shell from Grub menu, but I wouldn't know what to do with it (I tried the `devices` command, but I don't understand the output).

Comment: I believe the EFI setup is only available *before* the GRUB menu appears.

Comment: @chili555 idk, it's called EFI shell in the menu (it's actually on Arch Anarchy installer, not Ubuntu's).

Answer (score 0):

Is Secure Boot enabled and what Kernel are you using?

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image
```

Same issue here(Lenovo E585/AMD/Ryzen 2700u), no WIFI switch before Kernel 4.19. Disabling secure boot fixes it, but it is not an acceptable solution here.

```
mokutil  --sb-state
SecureBoot enabled
uname -r
5.0.0-050000rc7-generic
lspci -k | more
…
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 P
CI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
Kernel driver in use: r8169
Kernel modules: r8169
04:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device b822
Subsystem: Lenovo Device b024
Kernel driver in use: r8822be
```

Comment: No, secure boot is a no-go for virtually any Linux (it's a kind of a scam pulled out by MS to prevent people from using anything but Windows). I've tried with a bunch of different kernels 4.2...4.20, but the results were more or less the same.