# Wifi can not find any networks after kernel update

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

After the last update on Ubuntu 18.04 (4.15.0-142-generic) my wifi fails to find any networks.
[wifi not finding images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEB0M.jpg)

When I run `sudo lshw -C network` I get the following:

```
 *-generic DISABLED        
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Illegal Vendor ID
   vendor: Illegal Vendor ID
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
   logical name: wlp7s0
   version: ff
   serial: 28:3a:4d:7d:30:15
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 66MHz
   capabilities: bus_master vga_palette cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8822be driverversion=4.15.0-142-generic firmware=N/A latency=255 link=no maxlatency=255 mingnt=255 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:144 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:a4300000-a430ffff

 *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
   logical name: enp8s0
   version: 15
   serial: e8:6a:64:7e:19:c4
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:17 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a4204000-a4204fff memory:a4200000-a4203fff

 *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 3
   logical name: enp0s20f0u2
   serial: 02:61:1f:5b:f1:72
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.200.64 link=yes multicast=yes
```

and `ifconfig`:

```
enp0s20f0u2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.200.64  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.200.255
    inet6 fe80::6045:696e:c17d:8342  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 02:61:1f:5b:f1:72  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 13878  bytes 12536453 (12.5 MB)
    RX errors 8  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 8
    TX packets 8995  bytes 2533335 (2.5 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp8s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether e8:6a:64:7e:19:c4  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 622  bytes 55833 (55.8 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 622  bytes 55833 (55.8 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

If i try to `sudo ifconfig wlp7s0 up` I get `SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not permitted`

`dmesg`:

```
[   43.536416] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   43.536417] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   43.536418] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   46.696451] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s20f0u2: link is not ready
[   46.703136] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp8s0: link is not ready
[   46.774164] r8169 0000:08:00.0 enp8s0: link down
[   46.774317] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp8s0: link is not ready
[   46.802975] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp7s0: link is not ready
[   46.827476] r8822be: halmac_init_hal failed
[   46.951349] r8822be: halmac_init_hal failed
[   46.952202] r8822be: halmac_init_hal failed
[   49.495101] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found         
[Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20170831/nsarguments-100)
[   57.008614] r8822be: halmac_init_hal failed
[   57.009144] r8822be: halmac_init_hal failed
[   67.013206] r8822be: halmac_init_hal failed
[   67.013534] r8822be: halmac_init_hal failed
[   77.057025] r8822be: halmac_init_hal failed
[   77.057611] r8822be: halmac_init_hal failed
[   80.383128] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   80.383131] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   80.383133] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   83.289169] rfkill: input handler disabled
[   83.411293] acpi INT3400:00: Unsupported event [0x88]
[   84.429167] acpi INT3400:00: Unsupported event [0x88]
[   87.084368] r8822be: halmac_init_hal failed
[   87.085163] r8822be: halmac_init_hal failed
[   97.097929] r8822be: halmac_init_hal failed
[   97.098484] r8822be: halmac_init_hal failed
[  218.697420] acpi INT3400:00: Unsupported event [0x86]
[  352.725607] usb 1-3: USB disconnect, device number 3
[  446.861695] CPU8: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 3)
[  446.861696] CPU4: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4)
[  446.861697] CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4)
[  446.861697] CPU2: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 3)
[  446.861698] CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4)
[  446.861699] CPU7: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4)
[  446.861700] CPU6: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4)
[  446.861701] CPU10: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4)
[  446.861701] CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4)
[  446.861702] CPU8: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4)
[  446.861737] CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4)
[  446.861737] CPU9: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4)
[  446.861738] CPU11: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4)
[  446.861739] CPU5: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4)
[  446.862763] CPU8: Core temperature/speed normal
[  446.862764] CPU8: Package temperature/speed normal
[  446.862765] CPU0: Package temperature/speed normal
[  446.862765] CPU2: Core temperature/speed normal
[  446.862766] CPU4: Package temperature/speed normal
[  446.862767] CPU10: Package temperature/speed normal
[  446.862767] CPU6: Package temperature/speed normal
[  446.862767] CPU2: Package temperature/speed normal
[  446.862825] CPU1: Package temperature/speed normal
[  446.862826] CPU7: Package temperature/speed normal
[  446.862826] CPU9: Package temperature/speed normal
[  446.862827] CPU3: Package temperature/speed normal
[  446.862828] CPU11: Package temperature/speed normal
[  446.862828] CPU5: Package temperature/speed normal
[ 2826.974988] r8822be: halmac_init_hal failed
[ 2848.005392] r8822be: halmac_init_hal failed
```

I can't find a way to fix it by myself, would gladly accept any help
Thank you

EDIT:

`rfkill list all` :

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: "Illegal Vendor ID" ???? Not good...

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `rfkill list all` and also: `sudo dmesg | grep r88`

Comment: I actually just solved it by just loading windows and then loading ubuntu again (I have dual boot) as someone mentioned... Very weird but its working... also added rfkill list all for sports, and dmesg shows everything is ok with r8822be driver

Comment: Ubuntu 18?    Ubuntu desktop and server releases have a *yy.mm* format, and whilst specialist snap based releases like Ubuntu Core 18 for IoT appliances do use a *yy* format there are none titled just Ubuntu 18.  Please clarify your release as there is no Ubuntu 18.  FYI: Ubuntu 18.04 is the full system, Ubuntu Core 18 is a reduced system (which is a plus on limited devices, cloud setups etc.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just solved it by just loading windows and then loading ubuntu again (I have dual boot) as someone mentioned... Very weird but its working... also added rfkill list all for sport, and dmesg shows everything is ok with r8822be driver now

Comment: try if @J0h answer solve it for you too https://askubuntu.com/questions/1105025/rtl8822be-on-18-04-1-new-install-on-lenovo-legion-y530