# Installing/Uninstalling WiFi Drivers on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, realtek-wireless

I recently installed Ubuntu on my machine but I am running into a little issue : it doesn't detect any WiFi adaptors. I think it might be because I don't have the right drivers installed. After a little bit of researches on the Internet, I was able to identify the ethernet controller built in my laptop : Realtek Semiconductor TL 8111/8168/8411; and I was this site with (hopefully) the right driver for me : https://www.touslesdrivers.com/index.php?v_page=23&v_code=38271.
I downloaded it and I am now left with a file that I don't really know what to do with. I tried to follow the instructions in the README.txt file but couldn't make it work.

Here is what I am faced with :

It says (the README file) :
"If you are running the target kernel, then you should be able to do :

```
    # ./autorun.sh  (as root or with sudo)"
```

but when I try here is what the terminal says :

```
titouan@Laptop-Titouan:~/Téléchargements/r8168-8.036.00$ ./autorun.sh 

Check old driver and unload it.
Build the module and install
./autorun.sh: 27: ./autorun.sh: make: not found
titouan@Laptop-Titouan:~/Téléchargements/r8168-8.036.00$ sudo ./autorun.sh 
[sudo] Mot de passe de titouan : 

Check old driver and unload it.
Build the module and install
./autorun.sh: 27: ./autorun.sh: make: not found
titouan@Laptop-Titouan:~/Téléchargements/r8168-8.036.00$
```

I don'treally know what to do with this piece of information...
Btw I am not even sure the original problem comes from the drivers, but since I don't have any other idea...

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsusb`  The driver you downloaded is for ethernet and will not help wifi

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with Realtek wireless driver. The driver you described is Ethernet driver.

One possible solution for problem is to found in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1057903/968480

From this repo, you can find driver installation guide.
https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88

Also, some modules might conflict, so they have to be blacklisted with this command:

```
echo "blacklist ideapad-laptop" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

From my personal experience with the problem, I could recommend also trying to boot without powercable attatched after all the previous steps (if you run on a laptop of course), altough I don't understand the reasons, but it has worked for me.