# I can't find a wi-fi driver for my laptop Lenovo Ideapad L340 for Ubuntu 20

Tags: drivers, lenovo, realtek

I am new with Linux so I choose ubuntu, but I can't use my wi-fi.
I searched and tried `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` but nothing happened and it still not working....

I also tried `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and got this ...

```
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. 
RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]    
Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:c024] 
08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. 
RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)  
Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:38cf]
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem, look at the answer provided here [Installing/Uninstalling WiFi Drivers on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1274646/installing-uninstalling-wifi-drivers-on-ubuntu/1274654#1274654)

Basically you need to download and build the driver for for the Realtek wireless network card from this repo: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88

Install the drivers

```
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88.git  
cd rtw88  
make  
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtw_8822ce
```

And if still in trouble, try command, since there might be conflicting drivers.

`echo "blacklist ideapad-laptop" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

And reboot.

Comment: It is better to use dkms to install this driver.