# WiFi is not working in Lenovo E580 after installing Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, lenovo, realtek-wireless

I got a Lenovo ThinkPad E580 and I installed Ubuntu 18.04.
However, in WiFi settings, the message "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found" is displayed.
The "Additional Drivers" tab in "Software & Updates" doesn't show anything related to WiFi.
I also ran this command in the Terminal:

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3;rfkill list`:

```
Network controller [0280]:Realtek Semiconductor Co.,Ltd. Device [10ec:b822]
Subsystem:Lenovo Device[17aa:b024]
Kernel modules:r8822be
06:00.0 SD Host controller [0805]:02 Micro,Inc. SD/MMC Card Reader Controller[1217:8621](rev 01)
0:tpacpi_bluetooth_sw:Bluetooth
 soft blocked:no
 Hard blocked:no
2:hci0:Bluetooth
 soft blocked:yes
 Hard blocked:no
```

Comment: What is the exact response to the terminal command: `sudo modprobe r8822be` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everybody for giving answers. When I enter the `modprobe` command the response is

```
error:could not insert '8821ce':required key not available
```

It seems this issue happens only on UEFI systems with enabled Secure Boot. Then disabling Secure Boot in UEFI (BIOS) settings solved the problem.

Thanks once again for giving me a clue.

Answer (score 0):

Your machine is not detecting a wifi device only bluetooth.
Looks like you will need to build a kernel module for the realtek adapter.

You can try the instructions that chili555 posted in the link below

[Asus Rog Strix Z370 EGAMING Wireless card not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1004014/asus-rog-strix-z370-egaming-wireless-card-not-working)

Comment: I don't believe he needs to build the driver. It already exists in 18.04. It isn't loading as expected and we need to find out why.